# Ctrl+click on link in a browser doesn't open page in a new tab

Tags: google-chrome, touchpad, macbook, browser

I reinstalled Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and for the most part it went off without a hitch; however, my browser isn't acting right.  I often use the CTRL+click shortcut to open links in a new tab.  At first I thought the issue was with Chrome, but then I decided to try the same thing in FireFox and it doesn't work there either.

I run Ubuntu on a MacBook Air with a touchpad and no mouse.  I fooled around with the touchpad settings without any luck.

Comment: Can you provide a more concrete example? There are many links on many web sites today which break the "open in new tab" feature of browsers.

Comment: I don't use chrome. I don't see this problem in Firefox either. I can Ctrl+click on your name on this very page, and it opens your profile in a new window. If I Ctrl+click on "Add a new comment" however, it does not, but simply expands the comment entry box.

Comment: My question was whether you could provide a specific example that perhaps others could check against as well.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually discovered that CTRL cause a drag operation evidenced by the change in the mouse pointer.  By holding CTRL down I am able to drag a Window around not only by the title bar but by any part of the window including the hyperlink in the browser window.  I had to turn this off in Unity under Windows > Moving and Resizing Windows > Special Key to move and resize Windows > Alt.  (from Ctrl.)

Then under Mouse and Touchpad on the Touchpad tab I had to set Advanced > Two-finger click emulation > Middle Button, which apparently Chrome accepts as a mechanism for opening a link in a new tab.  So while I don't have CTRL+click on a link working I have a two-finger touchpad press on a link working, which is acceptable.

Later, I restarted Chrome and CTRL+click appeared to be working again.  Thus I suspect the first issue was the main thing.